# Android Activity not Retaining the Variables after being called by another Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am developing a Quizz App in which an activity shows question and options from SQLite and on selecting option, another activity is showing result for 2000 ms(it has a timer)and then it calls First Activity via an Intent.

So, Most of the interaction is between 2 activities. But each time my MainActivity is called, it re-initializes all the variables again and again.

I am opening my database connection in onCreate() and also keeping a counter (that can count how many questions have been asked yet) whose value is not retained after the intent from Second Activity. I am worried on how to solve this.

I am a bit confused about the life cycle that is followed. Whether the call to First Activity from Second one starting with onCreate() or it's also initializing the instance variables again.

This is onCreate() method I wrote:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected static final int SCORE_INCREMENT = 5;
    TextView question;
    Button score, opt1, opt2, opt3;
    MyDatabaseManager dbManager;
    QuizManager quizManager;
    private int quiz_counter =1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbManager = new MyDatabaseManager(getApplicationContext());
        dbManager.open();

        quizManager = new QuizManager(MainActivity.this, dbManager);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Asking The First Question", 0).show();

        askQuestion();
    }
    }
```

Is there any difference between the above written code and the one I am writing now... if the activity is called again via an Intent

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected static final int SCORE_INCREMENT = 5;
    TextView question;
    Button score, opt1, opt2, opt3;
    MyDatabaseManager dbManager  = new MyDatabaseManager(getApplicationContext());
    QuizManager quizManager  = new QuizManager(this, dbManager);
    private int quiz_counter =1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Asking The First Question", 0).show();

        askQuestion();
    }
    }
```

This might be a silly question. But it's a bit confusing for me. Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you have variables that you want to maintain between changing activities, then you should either

1. Store them in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

or

2. Pass them between the `Activites` in the `Intents` (see [Starting another activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html))

Comment: `SharedPreferences` should be used for data persistence (i.e. settings of for your app) and not for saving the state of an `Activity`. Sending variables that you want to maintain via an `Intent` will only work if the `Activity` is started for result. This is not the purpose of this mechanism anyway. What he wants to do is to [save the state of his `Activity`](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) using `onSaveInstanceState()`.

Comment: OP has specified second activity "calls First Activity via an Intent", instead of using the backstack. This suggests they are creating a new instance of the first activity each time, so passing the data via Intent is a valid solution. If, instead of creating a new instance of the first activity each time from the second activity, they just called finish() on the second activity using the backstack to return to the first activity, then I agree they should use onSaveInstanceState()